# Scala - Base Methods in a class

Tags: scala

Being a new learner in Scala world I'm confused with few **methods**(*Value Members*) which I have seen almost in every class.

E.g.  **++** , **++:** , **+:** , **:+** , **/:** , **:\**

Being a Java coder, all these above operators or methods are not familiar to me. If anyone can explain or share a link it'll great.

In Java, Object class have 11 methods those are base methods are these methods similar to those?

Comment: Here you go my friend.. http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.in/2008/12/scala-operator-cheat-sheet.html

Comment: Or http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html?search=:+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those operators you mentioned in your example are all methods defined for collections so they will be available for any collection type (which may be more than you think, for example String and Option are also collection types).

`++` and `++:` are used for concatenating two collections.

`+:` and `:+` are used for prepending and appending an element to a collection.

`/:` and `:\` are aliases for the `foldleft` and `foldright` methods, the symbolic operators are typically considered bad style and you should stick to just using the `foldleft` and `foldright` methods as that makes the code a bit more clear.

You should also be able to find all of these methods and others with an explanation in the scaladoc page for the type you find them on.